Error index page because of htaccess
My desktop index.html cannot be validated by Google Search Console. The error is " page with redirection ". I made a redirection for mobile users on the m. version of my website. Google is crawling my website with Google Bot for smartphone and then can't reach the desktop version of the index page. Is there something wrong in my htaccess?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.be/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
# Check if this is the noredirect query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)
# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:www.mysite.be]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Can not read and write cookie in same request, must duplicate condition
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) 

# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]

# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ https://m.mysite.be [R,L]



I don't personally see this as an error, just a limitation of Google Search Console.
Google will be crawling your site with bots other than "Googlebot smartphone". However, as far as I am aware, you cannot view the data gathered by the desktop bot in Search Console.  As such, that page should show as a redirect, as that is what Googlebot smartphone sees.
Google prioritise mobile, and don't actually recommend using an alternative mobile domain, with John Mueller saying:

So from our point of view, we don’t have well, at least as far as I
know, we don’t have any problems with m dot domains in general, in the
sense that this is one of the supported formats that we have for
mobile websites. We don’t recommend the m-dot setup. So if you’re
setting up a new website, I would try to avoid that as much as
possible, and instead use a responsive setup. But it is something that
can work.

It's worth reading Google's page on mobile-first indexing for alternative approaches and some possible gotchas to your current approach.
I'm assuming that your desktop version correctly appears in the SERPs when you search for your site on a desktop browser?  If so, I wouldn't worry too much about this.  It's just a limitation of Search Console - I guess they see adaptive design as an old-fashioned approach and not something worth giving Search Console users the ability to get full data on.
